# inno setup - SQL Server 2016 silent Installation prompts reboot

Tags: sql-server, inno-setup, sql-server-2016

I am trying to silent install SQL Server 2016 components using a configuration file from my installer using inno setup. The OS I am using is Windows Server 2012 R2.

SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is available as a separate installer from 2016 version on wards. So I am required to install the SQL Server first followed my SSMS executable through my installer in one shot.

The problem is, the SQL Server is installed correctly but requires a system reboot before installing the SSMS executable. I tried using `/SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck` parameter when I execute the `Setup.exe` and deleting the `PendingFileRenameOperations` registry entry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`) after the installation of SQL Server. But it still requires a system reboot.

Is there a way to skip the system reboot or any other work around possible for my requirement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried installing SSMS first?

Comment: No I did not try the other way. Is it possible? I will try it once.

Comment: Yes, you can install SSMS first (SSMS does not need SQL Server on the same box to function).  I think the only dependency is .Net 4.6.  I can't remember if the SSMS install requires a reboot.  My gut feeling is, it does not.

Comment: The SSMS was installed successfully. But the SQL Server featured hanged with the message "SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation". I have to look up for some other way it seems. Thanks for the suggestion @destination-data.

Comment: If the reboot is interfering with your installer, you could use [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) instead.  [Workflows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166839/powershell-reboot-and-continue-script) can perform an action, reboot a machine, and then continue executing when it comes back on line.

Comment: Just thinking; you might find [PowerShell's new desired state configuration](https://chrislumnah.com/2017/03/07/dsc-install-of-sql-server/) useful.  With DSC, you define what you want, rather than how to achieve it.  I.e.  I want SQL Server and SSMS.  Window's then figures out how to deliver this.

Comment: @destination-data, my requirement has been modified. But I will make sure to use the approach you have proposed in future challenges. Thanks a ton.