# Exit and Continue script (for example to take PATH environment change effect)

Tags: powershell

**Context**

When a PowerShell script installs components what modifies environment variables like PATH. This takes effect only when I close the console window, then reopen another.

If the following commands require the the changed environment, they will fail.

**Question**

I would like to run such a script without manual intervention, how can accomplish this? I found [Powershell - Reboot and Continue Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15166839/1157814), but that would be overkill. Is there any similar just to exit, then continue?

Comment: It is not only about the PATH, that is just an example.

Comment: The answer would be the same for any other environment variable.

Comment: All methods described the referenced Q/A (for example 'refreshenv' has only effect on the Poweshell state. If the PATH changes, even after refreshenv, or more: start powershell, or start-process, the newly added command will not found. If I manually start a new PowerShell window, there it is...

Comment: Enumerating the environment variables from the registry, and then reloading each of them is what I'd try first. If that doesn't help you need to investigate where the sessions differ. Just restarting a new PowerShell instance and terminating the old one could be done via `Start-Process powershell.exe; exit`, but there is no simple way to resume operation in the new instance, so reloading the environment in the current instance would be the preferred approach.