# Run more commands before the reboot

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to run more commands when the Restart-Computer command issued? If yes, can you guys please send some example?

Comment: Have a look here https://superuser.com/questions/165142/using-task-scheduler-to-run-a-task-before-shutdown

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. The link shows that you have to create or put the script on the shutdown task or group policy. Is there a way to continue to run one long script even though the Restart-Computer command was issued with a delay or after all PS commands were issued?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [Powershell - Reboot and Continue Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15166839/3744182)